# Application visibility in odoo depending on logged in user

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I am new to odoo. I need to setup different types of user login, and depending on the type of user logging in, i need to hide/show apps i have installed. I have already read about access rights and they seem to be used on models, restricting access to users. Is there a way i can hide/show an app based on the type of user logging in? I am using odoo v12 community edition.

Comment: Access groups is the way to go. You can set groups on some technical models like menu items. Only set groups are able to see those menu items. And there is way more you can do with groups, but the whole security mechanism in Odoo is so complex, you can write a book about it ;-)

Comment: Each new model requires a new security group set up.  This means that if you create, for example, a purchase request module, you would have to create purchase.request and purchase.request.line.  Each of these models (or classes) requires at least a base level of security, even if it is everyone gets read,write,create,delete access.